# event notifications not received as described

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, com, notifications, connection-points

**Problem:**

- **Event notifications** (From COM object - Server) are not received as listed in the Sink (class) implementation.
- **One event notification** is **received** (Event_one), however, others are **not** received accordingly
- If **order** is **changed** - in IDispatch::Invoke, that is:

  - if `Event_one` is swapped to `Event_two` then `Event_two` notification received but `Event_one` and others neglected accordingly

**Question:**

- Better way to implement, IDispatch::Invoke or QI?
- Using the wrong logic or approach?

**Note**:

- No MFC
- No ATL
- Pure C++
- using message loop: [GetMessage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644936(VS.85).aspx)
- **STA** model ( Coinitialize() )
- Call to IDispatch::Advise **successful** (HRESULT from call **S_OK**)
- After above, COM object method calls as normal (with interface pointer)
- Single call to Advise
- Type library generated from [MIDL compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367300(VS.85).aspx)

**For instance (example):**

Illustration of **IDispatch::Invoke** - taken from **Sink Class**:

```
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Invoke(
{
//omitted parameters

// The riid parameter is always supposed to be IID_NULL
        if (riid != IID_NULL)
            return DISP_E_UNKNOWNINTERFACE;

if (pDispParams) //DISPID dispIdMember
    {
        switch (dispIdMember) { 
        case 1:
            return Event_one();
        case 2:
            return Event_two();
        case 3:
            return Event_three();
        default:
            return E_NOTIMPL;
        }
    }
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}
```

---

Illustration of **QueryInterface:**

```
STDMETHOD (QueryInterface)(
//omitted parameters
{
    if (iid == IID_IUnknown || iid == __uuidof(IEvents))
    {
        *ppvObject = (IEvents *)this;
    } else {
        *ppvObject = NULL;
        return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }
    m_dwRefCount++;
    return S_OK;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SOLVED:

After reviewing the corresponding **IDL** FILE (generated by the MIDL compiler), it was evident that each **method** contained in the **IEvent** interface, has a **unique ID**. For instance, `Event_one` has an ID of **2**. For example:

```
methods:
    [id(0x00000002)]
    HRESULT Event_one();
```

Therefore, making a change as followings - in the IDispatch::invoke implementation (illustrated in the above question):

```
//omitted


if (pDispParams) //DISPID dispIdMember
        {
            switch (dispIdMember) { 
            case 2:
                    return Event_one();

//omitted
```

Now when invoked accordingly, the desired/correct **method** is **now** executed.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are receiving the notification for first method of the sink interface, I suspect, events are not sent on other methods from Server. If you have code of the server, just check the  connection point class which throws the notifications.

You can also put a breakpoint in Invoke method of client application to check what are all the events it is receiving.

Comment: @Vinay: +1 your suggestion helped locate the problem - I'm grateful